# Regular Expressions (pcre) for shortcode/bbcode

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a regex (see on https://regex101.com/r/mB7vQ8/2):

```
/\[content_box((.*?)!?\])(.*?)\[\/content_box\]/ig
```

for match all `[content_box]` (with or without tag parameters) in a text like:

```
[content_boxes foo=bar][content_box baz=foo]text[/content_box][/content_boxes]
[content_box]text[/content_box]
[content_box foo=bar]text[/content_box]
```

My regex work, but if `[content_box]` is included in a `[content_boxes]` the rule fails the match (in strong):

> **[content_boxes foo=bar][content_box baz=foo]text[/content_box]**[/content_boxes]
>
> **[content_box]text[/content_box]**
>
> **[content_box foo=bar]text[/content_box]**

the expected match is:

> [content_boxes foo=bar]**[content_box baz=foo]text[/content_box]**[/content_boxes]
>
> **[content_box]text[/content_box]**
>
> **[content_box foo=bar]text[/content_box]**

see online https://regex101.com/r/mB7vQ8/2

How solve it?

Comment: There is a little thing that I didn't understand. You say `but if [content_boxes] is included in a [content_boxes]` but your example shows a `[content_box]` singular inside a `[content_boxes]` plural. Was that a typo?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm sorry it is a typo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex with word boundaries:

```
~\[content_box\b\s*([^]]*)\](.*?)\[/content_box\]~
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mB7vQ8/5)

Here `content_box\b` will not match `content_boxes` and match will always be inner `[content_box ..]` tag.

Comment: I think he also need the `[^]]*` grouped from his regex